# Is it possible to update all attributes in class instance by changing just one attribute?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I'd like to update all attributes in my class, if I change at least one attribute, here's my example in `Python`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list
        self.list_len = len(self.my_list)
    def update_list(self, var1):
        self.my_list.append(var1)
```

if I create an instance of `class A` with initial list of 3 elements and call `list_len` attribute, I get:

```
a_instance = A([1,2,3])
a_instance.list_len

[Out]: 3
```

but if I update `my_list`, the `list_len` attribute is unchanged, is it possible to update this attribute if `my_list` is changed without calling `update_list_len`-like methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `list_len` to `@property`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    @property
    def list_len(self):
        return len(self.my_list)


a_instance = A([1, 2, 3])
print(a_instance.list_len)

a_instance.my_list.append(4)
print(a_instance.list_len)
```

Prints:

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways:

Method 1: update the `list_len` whenever you update `my_list`. This is usually not the best way since you are wasting a variable just to duplicate a value that is already available somewhere else.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list
        self.list_len = len(my_list)

    def update_list(self, var1):
        self.my_list.append(var1)
        self.list_len = len(self.my_list)

a_instance = A([1, 2, 3])
print(a_instance.list_len)  # Prints 3
a_instance.update_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(a_instance.list_len)  # Prints 5
```

Method 2: instead of variable `list_len` make a getter function that will give you the current length:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def update_list(self, var1):
        self.my_list.append(var1)

    def list_len(self):
        return len(self.my_list)

a_instance = A([1, 2, 3])
print(a_instance.list_len())  # Prints 3
a_instance.update_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(a_instance.list_len())  # Prints 5
```

Method 3 (best): use getter property, which is similar to Method 2 but with a bit of syntactic sugar:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def update_list(self, var1):
        self.my_list.append(var1)

    @property
    def list_len(self):
        return len(self.my_list)

a_instance = A([1, 2, 3])
print(a_instance.list_len)  # Prints 3
a_instance.update_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(a_instance.list_len)  # Prints 5
```